# How to iterate over all overlapping matches in string?

Tags: python, regex

I want to iterate over all overlapping matches of terms in a sentence/string. If it is not possible to solve the problem with just a single regex, it is fine to go with more than one -- but the number of expressions should be independent of the number of terms.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'X has effect on Y.'
>>> terms = ['has effect', 'effect', 'effect on']
>>> pattern = r"(?=\b(" + "|".join(re.escape(term) for term in terms) + r")\b)"
>>> print pattern
(?=\b(has\ effect|effect|effect\ on)\b)
>>> [(m.span(1), text[m.start(1):m.end(1)]) for m in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
[((2, 12), 'has effect'), ((6, 12), 'effect')]
```

I'm still not able to extract 'effect on' term -- I think I stuck with 'lookbehind assertion'. Thanks!

EDIT #1:

Problem description in terms of input/output specs with example:

Input:

- a sentence, e.g. `'X has effect on Y.'`
- a list of terms, e.g. `['has effect', 'effect', 'effect on']`

Output:

- a list of mentions (`((start, end), term)` tuples), e.g. `[((2, 12), 'has effect'), ((6, 12), 'effect'), ((6, 15), 'effect on')]`

Comment: Are we required to use regex only? :)

Comment: @DavidSilveiro -- no, I'm quite agnostic about the final solution. But I would really like to see 'regex solution' because I've been stuck in this for a few hours. :)

Comment: Do you need to get `has effect`, `effect` and `effect on` or just `has effect`, `effect on`?

Comment: All the 'mentions' -- `has effect`, `effect` and `effect on`. Thanks

Comment: Then it is not possible to do just with regex as the regex engine with `re.findall` or `re.finditer` tests each position in the string once.

Comment: I don't understand why this needs a complex regex. Can't you just use 3 separate expressions?

Comment: @Ralf -- this is just a MRE, actual list of terms is quite long. I don't want to iterate over the list of terms and apply re.finditer() foreach.

Comment: @kkor Why not? Are there concrete requirements you did not mention here? Also one big regex might not necesarily be much faster than using many simple regexes; you need to benchmark your specific use case to know which one is faster (if speed is a concern for you).

Comment: Well, this is the most readable and easily maintainable approach.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide a specific example of what you are trying to achieve? I mean, what is your expected output?

Comment: @Ralf -- thanks, but I've already done that analysis. The solution (which is incomplete, at the moment) is 20x faster than multiple expressions -- so I hope it is possible to keep the similar performance.

Comment: Will the list of terms always contain the terms in the order they appear in the text?

Comment: @josoler -- thank you! I've just edited problem description.

Comment: @wwii -- no, it cannot be assumed.

Comment: **No, it is not possible**. Your solution is not incomplete, it is just wrong for this type of job.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to search for each term independently starting at the beginning of the text each time.

Comment: `... but I've already done that analysis...` - a solution that doesn't work never compares favorably to one that does by any metric.